# Find the $\sum\limits_{sym}ab$ maximum of the value

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

Let $a,b,c,d,e\in (0,1)$ and such $$a+b+c+d+e=1$$
find the maximun of the value
$$S=ab+ac+ad+ae+bc+bd+be+cd+ce+de$$

I Conjecture the maximun is $\dfrac{2}{5}?$,such  $a=b=c=d=e=\dfrac{1}{5}$,so $$S\le\dfrac{10}{25}=\dfrac{2}{5}?$$
right?Thanks,

Comment: Note that $a, b, c, d, e$ need not be restricted to $(0, 1)$.  As long as the sum is $1$ and the numbers real, your conjecture holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1=(a+b+c+d+e)^2 \geqslant \sum_{cyc} a^2 + 2S$$

Further from CS inequality
$$(1+1+1+1+1) \cdot\sum_{cyc} a^2 \geqslant \left(\sum_{cyc} a \right)^2=1$$

Thus $1 \geqslant \frac15+2S \implies S \leqslant \frac25 $

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$4(a+b+c+d+e)^2-10(ab+ac+ad+ae+bc+bd+ce+cd+ce+de)=$$
$$=(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(a-d)^2+(a-e)^2+(b-c)^2+(b-d)^2+(b-e)^2+(c-d)^2+(c-e)^2+(d-e)^2\geq0$$
so the answer is $\frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: Nice,so for any $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}=1$,then we have $$\sum_{sym}a_{1}a_{2}\le \dfrac{\binom{n}{2}}{n^2}=\dfrac{n-1}{2n}$$?

Comment: Not exactly! $\sum\limits_{sym}a_1a_2=2(n-2)!\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n}a_ia_j$

Comment: @Michale,oh,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = \left( a , a, a , a ,  b, b, b , c, c, d \right)$ and $v = (b,c,d,e,c,d,e,d,e,e)$. Then by Cauchy-Schwartz
\begin{align}
a(b+c+d+e)+b(c+d+e)+c(d+e)+de=\langle u,v \rangle \le \|u\| \| v\|
\end{align}
with equality if and only if $v = \lambda u$, since $v \neq 0$ and $u\neq 0$.
So in particular the maximum is when $a = \lambda b$, $a = \lambda c$, $a = \lambda d$ and $a = \lambda e$ from the first 4 coordinates.
From the fifth coordinate we have $b = \lambda c = \lambda^2 b$, so $\lambda \in \{-1,1\}$.
As $a,b,c,d,e \ge 0$, we must have $\lambda = 1$, and thus the maximum is indeed when $a=b=c=d=e = \frac{1}{5}$.